# Cannot connect to kubernetes pod from master: i/o timeout

Tags: kubernetes

I configured kubernetes cluster with one master and one node, the machines that run master and node aren't in the same network. For networking I installed calico and all the pods are running. For testing the cluster I used [get shell example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/) and when I run the following command from master machine:

```
kubectl exec -it shell-demo -- /bin/bash
```

I received the error:

```
Error from server: error dialing backend: dial tcp 10.138.0.2:10250: i/o timeout
```

The ip 10.138.0.2 is on eth0 interface on the node machine.

What configuration do I need to make to access the pod from master?

**EDIT**

kubectl get all --all-namespaces -o wide output:

```
default       shell-demo                           1/1       Running   0          10s       192.168.4.2   node-1
kube-system   calico-node-7wlqw                    2/2       Running   0          49m       10.156.0.2    instance-1
kube-system   calico-node-lnk6d                    2/2       Running   0          35s       10.132.0.2    node-1
kube-system   coredns-78fcdf6894-cxgc2             1/1       Running   0          50m       192.168.0.5   instance-1
kube-system   coredns-78fcdf6894-gwwjp             1/1       Running   0          50m       192.168.0.4   instance-1
kube-system   etcd-instance-1                      1/1       Running   0          49m       10.156.0.2    instance-1
kube-system   kube-apiserver-instance-1            1/1       Running   0          49m       10.156.0.2    instance-1
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-instance-1   1/1       Running   0          49m       10.156.0.2    instance-1
kube-system   kube-proxy-b64b5                     1/1       Running   0          50m       10.156.0.2    instance-1
kube-system   kube-proxy-xxkn4                     1/1       Running   0          35s       10.132.0.2    node-1
kube-system   kube-scheduler-instance-1            1/1       Running   0          49m       10.156.0.2    instance-1
```

Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like a firewall rule needs to be modified to allow access to port 10250 from whichever machines you would expect to use `exec` or `logs`, since both of those commands connect directly to the `kubelet` on the Nodes

Comment: All firewall rules are disable. I tried accessing the pod from master. I think the problem is the fact that kubernetes tries to access the pod thourgh the private ip "10.138.0.2".

Comment: show output for `kubectl get all --all-namespaces=true` command

Comment: I added it above. Thanks!

Comment: _kubernetes tries to access the pod thourgh the private ip "10.138.0.2"_ well, what IP would you _prefer_ it used? Just for extreme clarity: `exec` and `logs` do not use the SDN, they always travel over the "host" network, because they are designed to be accessed by your workstation, not from within the cluster.

Comment: @Dorin, are you sure your firewall is completely disabled?

Answer (score 1):

Before checking your status on Master .Please verify below things.

Please run below commands to check cluster info :

```
setenforce 0
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=6443/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=2379-2380/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=10250/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=10251/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=10252/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=10255/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
modprobe br_netfilter
echo '1' > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables
```

Run above command on both Master and worker node.

Then run below commands to check node status.

**kubectl get nodes**

Comment: I ran all commands but I received the same error. I think the problem is the fact that kubernetes tries to access the pod thourgh the private ip "10.138.0.2"

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too.  Don't know if you're on Azure, but I am, and I solved this by deleting the tunnelfront pod and letting Kubernetes restart it:

```
kubectl -n kube-system delete po -l component=tunnel
```

which is a solution I got from [here](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/232#issuecomment-403484459)

Answer (score 0):

we had the same problem, and in the end we found that we have 2 Nic per host, and they have 2 different IPs, and the route is also messed up. so when this timeout happens, check your networking setup, make sure your network is healthy and that should give you some good clue there.